# How to send data with NavigationComponent in Android

Tags: android

In my application I have 2 fragment and for show these I use NavigationComponent and I want sent some data.
**My navigation codes:**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
    app:startDestination="@id/recipesFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/recipesFragment"
        android:name="myapp.ui.fragments.recipe.RecipesFragment"
        android:label="@string/recipes"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_recipes" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_recipesFragment_to_menuFragment"
            app:destination="@id/menuFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="isUpdatedData"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
    </fragment>

    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/menuFragment"
        android:name="myapp.ui.fragments.recipe.menu.MenuFragment"
        android:label="fragment_menu"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_menu" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_menuFragment_to_recipesFragment"
            app:destination="@id/recipesFragment" />
    </dialog>
</navigation>
```

I set argument with default value, but when use this action into **MenuFragment** not access to me for set value! 
**MenuFragment codes:**

```
submitBtn.setOnClickListener {
                val action = MenuFragmentDirections.actionMenuFragmentToRecipesFragment(true)
                findNavController().navigate(action)
            }
```

When write **true** for value of `actionMenuFragmentToRecipesFragment` show me below error:

```
Too many arguments for public open fun actionMenuFragmentToRecipesFragment(): MenuFragmentDirections.ActionMenuFragmentToRecipesFragment defined in myapp.ui.fragments.recipe.menu.MenuFragmentDirections
```

[image]

How can I fix it and set **data** with `defaultValue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I hope this answer be useful for you
if you would like to use default value below code will help you:
`findNavController().navigate(MenuFragmentDirections.actionMenuFragmentToRecipesFragment().setIsUpdatedData(true))`
when you set default value for your argument compiler recognize code does not need setter and if you want change it you have to call setter method of argument in your navigation for custom fragment